# Google Sign in with WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, jwt, google-signin, openid-connect

I've been working at this for over a week now. I have successfully set up Owin using UseWsFederationAuthentication with UseCookieAuthentication for a client recently, but I'm struggling with Google's OpenID Connect for another project. I have registered my application with Google using the Google API dashboard. In the browser I am able to use

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
```

to get a JWT token. In my Owin ConfigureAuth I tried using the following:

```
AppBuilder.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
    new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
         {
           AllowedAudiences = new string[] { audience },
           AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
           IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new                    
               IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
               {
                   new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
               }
          });
```

I've also tried setting the TokenValidationParameters to basically not do any validation.

```
new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateActor = false,
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateIssuer = false,                                        
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
    RequireSignedTokens = false,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    RequireExpirationTime = false,
}
```

I've also tried setting the TokenValidationParameters similar to the way it was done here https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-csharp/blob/master/verifytoken.ashx.cs.

I've tried a lot of other things as well, but with no Joy. My requirements are to have an SPA call a .Net Web API with an authentication token that will be used to verify his ID. The application cannot rely on cookies and the JWT must be processed each time.

I'm at my wits end, or in other words help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope!